# Retrocomputing Reputation Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, reputation-graph

On my user page [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/277/wizzwizz2?tab=summary) I appear to have 5 less reputation than I should.
[image: The reputation conflict] [image: The proof of earnings]

Edit : I apologize for for the inconvenience... It appears to be solved.

Comment: Calculation error. Wait for the next rep recalc, usually within 24 hours. You're a mod there, so you can check your own user history to verify when it's happened.

Comment: @ArtOfCode That's wizzwizz4, not me...

Comment: Case of mistaken identity... In that case, you can ask your name-mate to verify when it takes place.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Is that correct use of Mod Privileges?

Comment: Yeah, no reason why he can't do that. It's just giving you information about yourself, and it can't be used for any other purposes, really.

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to Retrocomputing meta since isn't network-wide?

Comment: @JAL no, as this can happen in any site.

Comment: This looks to have already fixed itself - or am I wrong?

Comment: @MarcGravell You're right by the looks. Rep matches at 161 on the graph and the text score.

Comment: k, I'll mark this as completed, although it was the background activity that quietly fixed things

Comment: @Mark since no bug was fixed, maybe better use [tag:status-norepro] or [tag:status-bydesign], and mentioning in an answer that in similar cases, one has to wait for a day before reporting to give a chance to the "background activity" to fix it?

Comment: I'm still 5 rep too low...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else in this situation, be patient and wait 24 hours - a few days, and a reputation recalculation should occur and automatically fix the issue.